# Downloaded Dropbox files corrupted

Tags: java

I made a program that downloads .zip archives from Dropbox, which the client uses, but every time I try to open the archives, it says "Can not open file 'file location' as archive" How can I fix this from happening?

```
public void modDownload(String url, String filename) {
    try {
        URL dropbox = new URL(url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(dropbox.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(appdata + filename);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch(Exception e) {      
    }
}
```

And I call it like this

```
modDownload("https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8itscdtu81jj2z/armorhud.zip",
            "armorhud.zip");
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't think it's the URL that's causing the problem
Also, all of the other threads I checked out that stackoverflow suggested(and when I googeled) the problem, all of the answers didn't help, or I didn't understand them(as in it was explained poorly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the link you posted in your browser, hover over the 'Download' button. If you click that button, a new link will be invoked. That is the link you will need to use in your code. This is the link I got from clicking the Download button on your download page:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a8itscdtu81jj2z/armorhud.zip?token_hash=AAGVg84Z26vkuqJO-3bAX6BEQREt0UDtiDRkGZXWWa1y9A&dl=1

However, I am not sure how dropbox indexes their files, so the link might change by the time you read this answer.

Comment: dl=1 forces the download, without having he need to click on the "Download" button. As suggested here: [https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the location you specified: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8itscdtu81jj2z/armorhud.zip`, you get presented with a page that includes a download button.  You can't expect your code to automatically think to go to the URL that the download button will send you.

What it is attempting to do is download the HTML page as a ZIP file, which is why it can't open it as an archive.  An HTML file is not an archive.  Change your URL to the actual location of the **file** to be downloaded.

Also, take a look at the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core) and other APIs there if you want a better way of interfacing files with your application.

Answer (score 0):

just replace www with dl in your file url if it lives in your public area, otherwise you'll need to "get link" by right-clicking the file. if you do this via your web explorer it will be ready to use, if you do it via right-clicking in your file explorer you'll need to change www to dl